# Show Video on external Screen using AirPlay and AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avplayer, airplay

I am using Apple Airplay and `AVPlayer` to show a video on an external display, while showing some controls on the device using Apple TV and AirPlay.

I am using this class to display the `AVPlayer` on the external screen:

```
#import "AirPlayViewController.h"

@interface AirPlayViewController ()

@end

@implementation AirPlayViewController

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)iFrame{
    self.view.frame = iFrame;

    self.backGroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:iFrame];
    [self.view addSubview: self.backGroundImageView];

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [audioVideoPlayer pause];
}

-(void)playMediaWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL{
    audioVideoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:aURL];
    audioVideoPlayer.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive=YES;
    audioVideoPlayer.allowsExternalPlayback= YES;

    //manually resizing and adding the layer, so that the app does not get confused with airplayfunctionality
    AVPlayerLayer* playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: audioVideoPlayer];
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    if (audioVideoPlayer) {
        [audioVideoPlayer play];
    }
}

-(void)stopMediaPlayback{
    [audioVideoPlayer pause];
    [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: audioVideoPlayer] removeFromSuperlayer];
    audioVideoPlayer = nil;
}

@end
```

The problem I have is right there in `playMediaWithURL:`. The `AVPlayer` layer is not automatically added to the external screen but I have to add it by hand, which feels kind of dirty and leads to all kind of clean-up work when I want to remove the `AVPlayer` from the view again.

Has anyone else had trouble with this and found some neat way to implement it?

The `airPlayViewController` is called from another `UIViewController` that contains the second window along with all the AirPlay delegate stuff to display it, using this function:

```
- (void)setupMirroringForScreen:(UIScreen *)anExternalScreen{
    //find the correct resolution for the external screen
    UIScreen *tScreen= anExternalScreen;
    CGSize max = {0, 0};
    UIScreenMode *maxScreenMode = nil;

    for (UIScreenMode *current in tScreen.availableModes) {
        if (maxScreenMode == nil || current.size.height > max.height || current.size.width > max.width) {
            max = current.size;
            maxScreenMode = current;
        }
    }
    tScreen.currentMode = maxScreenMode;

    // Setup window in external screen
    self.externalWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:tScreen.bounds];
    self.externalWindow.hidden = NO;
    self.externalWindow.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
    self.externalWindow.screen = tScreen;

    self.airPlayVC = [[AirPlayViewController alloc]initWithFrame:tScreen.bounds];
    [self.airPlayVC.backGroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:mainMenuExternalBackgroundImage]];

    //try to play a video on the external Screen/ Audio file as fallback
    NSURL *tURL= [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:mainMenuVideo withExtension:nil];
    if (!tURL) {
        tURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:mainMenuAmbienceMusic withExtension:nil];
    }
    [self.airPlayVC playMediaWithURL:tURL];
    [self.externalWindow addSubview:self.airPlayVC.view];

}
```

Comment: To Clarify: The Audio Playback is fine anyway, and if I add the Playerlayer the way I do in my code the video is also displayed and the autosizing and everything works fine. It just doesn't feel right to ad the layer by hand, so I am looking for a better way to implement this

Comment: Hey Kim, in the end I sticked with the above solution.